# Remove words except last one in String

Tags: dart

I have a String with different value every time:

```
String words = "My name is Rob Joe";
```

I want to get only last word

`Joe`

but every time I don't know how many words the string consists of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String words = "My name is Rob Joe";
var array = words.split(" "); // <-- [My, name, is, Rob, Joe]
print(array.last); // output 'Joe'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter(Dart), you can get the last word of a string by splitting the string into an array of substrings using the split method and then accessing the last element of the resulting array. Here's an example:

```
   String words = "My name is Rob Joe";
   List<String> wordsArray = myString.split(" ");
   String lastWord = wordsArray[wordsArray.length - 1];
   print(lastWord); // "Joe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, you can also use `substring` and `lastIndexOf`:

```dart
final words = "My name is Rob Joe";
final lastWord = words.substring(words.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
print(lastWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last *word*, you should first properly define what a "word" is.

It's clearly obvious here, which is why it's doubly important to write it down, because something else may be just as obvious to someone else.
(Read: Nothing is obvious. Document it all!)

But let's say that a word is a maximal contiguous sequence of ASCII letters.
Then that's what you should look for.

Splitting on space characters works for *this* string, but won't if you have punctuation, or trailing whitespace, or any number of other complications.

I'd probably use a `RegExp`:

```dart
  // Matches a word. If used properly, only matches entire words.
  var wordRE = RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z]+"); 
 
  // Assume at least one word in `words`. Otherwise need more error handling.
  var lastWord = wordRe.allMatches(words).last[0]!;
```

This can be a little inefficient, if the string is long.
Another approach that *might* be more efficient, depending on the `RegExp` implementation, is to search backwards:

```dart
  /// Captures first sequence of [a-zA-Z]+ looking backwards from end.
  var lastWordRE = RegExp(r"$(?<=([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]*)");

  var lastWord = lastWordRE.firstMatch(words)?[1]!;
```

If you don't want to rely on RegExps (which are admittedly not that readable, and their performance is not always predictable), you can search for letters manually:

```dart
  String? lastWord(String words) {
    var cursor = words.length;
    while (--cursor >= 0) {
      if (_isLetter(words, cursor)) {
        var start = 0;
        var end = cursor + 1;
        while (--cursor >= 0) {
          if (!_isLetter(words, prev)) {
            start = cursor + 1;
            break;
          }
        }
        return words.substring(start, end);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
   
  bool _isLetter(String string, int index) {
    var char = string.codeUnitAt(index) | 0x20; // lower-case if letter.
    return char >= 0x61 /*a*/ && char <= 0x7a /*z*/;
  }
```

But first of all, decide what a word is.

Some very real words in common sentences might contain, e.g., `'` or `-`, but whether they matter to you or not depends on your use-case.
More exotic cases may need you to decide whether"e.g." is one word or two? Is `and/or`? Is `i18n`?
Depends on what it'll be used for.